# Is there any way in libradius to get RADIUS ip address of the server which actually responded request

Tags: c, unix, radius

I'm using libradius in my app.
The structure **struct rad_handle** where this info is available after call of **rad_send_request()** is private, so i can't access **h->servers[h->srv].addr** from my app.

Is there any way to know which one from several RADIUS servers i previously added with **rad_add_server()** responded to my **RAD_ACCESS_REQUEST** sent by **rad_send_request()**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way with the libradius API to determine this information.

Once you've received the response from the server, it's already discarded the information about what server address replied to it.

Your only option would be to make a customized version of libradius that populated this information.

The library itself is quite small, so understanding it in order to make changes of that kind should be quite simple.

> This is of course, assuming the [bsd libradius](https://www.gitorious.org/freebsd/freebsd/source/f1d6f4778d2044502209708bc167c05f9aa48615:lib/libradius), and not the [FreeRadius Client Library](http://freeradius.org/freeradius-client/)